# Runtime error 424 when adding parameters to ADODB Command in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm developing an Excel spreadsheet app that connects to an Access database. I'm able to query the database just fine. The problem occurs when I try to add parameters to a query - I'm getting **Runtime Error 424 - Object required**. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
Sub TestQuery()
Dim databaseFile As String
databaseFile = Range("DatabaseFilename").Value

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim connString As String
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & databaseFile & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
conn.Open (connString)

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Weights WHERE ID=?"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Parameters.Append (.CreateParameter("id", adVarChar, adParamInput, Value:="RIC"))
    cmd.Execute
End With

conn.Close
End Sub
```

The error occurs when it hits the .Parameters.Append line. Oddly enough, if I put a breakpoint right before that line and inspect the cmd object, it shows that the Parameters collection holds a single item...as if it's detected and added the parameter from the query string automatically. And if I set the data type and value of that item manually without adding it explicitly, it works. But that doesn't seem right. Every example that I've looked at adds the parameters explicitly. What is causing this error?

Comment: Try without brackets around `.CreateParameter`

Comment: @CDP1802 That results in Run-time error 3708 - Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

Comment: Add the size for the varchar ie 20 after adParamInput

Comment: @CDP1802 - That did it! Do you know why the parentheses need to be removed? And why do the sizes have to be added if those are optional arguments?

Comment: See [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver16) for variable length data types. With the () the object is evaluated as an expression.